# How to load another powershell file before the CmdletBinding?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am using powershell 5. I created an enum in different ps1 file and I like to load it in another ps1 that has CmdletBinding.

I tried the code below but didn't work. Is there any way to load the enum ps1 before the CmdletBinding?

```
. ".\GeneratorType.ps1" 

[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,Mandatory=$False)]       
        [GeneratorType]$type = [GeneratorType]::All
)
```

Comment: Tricky. Works with a function, but not without. It seems `[CmdletBinding()]` has to come first ...

Comment: Yes. I noticed that too. If I don't use that enum in parameter, I can load it after `CmdletBinding` but I like to use the enum in one of my parameters. The only solution that I found is to define that enum type in same file. I don't want to put `CmdletBinding` inside the function too.

Comment: You can always dot-source the class script outside of the cmdlet script, before calling it, like a wrapper script :-) or build the class in your profile

Comment: Thanks @sodawillow and @ Mathias R. Jessen .. I will look at that module. but I thought its gonna be overkill for my simple script https://github.com/michaelsync/powershell-scripts/tree/master/SqlTableTypeToDataType ... If using the module is the only way then I will just declare that enum in the same file.

Comment: @MichaelSync How do you define your enum in the same file? It still has to be defined after `CmdletBinding`, thus still being unknown in the parameter block. Can you post an answer on how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Think of it like this: A PowerShell script is a self-contained ScriptBlock.

The `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute is part of the `param-block`. According to the language specification, a param-block must be the first part of the ScriptBlock if present.

So no, you cannot put anything before the `CmdletBinding` attribute.

What you can do, is to convert your `GeneratorTypes.ps1` script to a module and use

```
#Requires -Modules
```

to make sure it's loaded when the param block is interpreted.